Firebase Cloud Messaging HTTP V1 Api giving 403 error
When I use Firebase Cloud Messaging Http V1 Api I get this error:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403, 
    "message": "Method doesn't allow unregistered callers (callers without established identity). Please use API Key or other form of API consumer identity to call this API.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Method doesn't allow unregistered callers (callers without established identity). Please use API Key or other form of API consumer identity to call this API.", 
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" 
  }
}

This is my code:
public function sendNotification($topic, $body, $ticket_id, $sound = 'bell.caf'){
        $data = [
            "to" => $topic,
            "notification" =>
                [
                    "title" => config('app.name'),
                    "body" => $body,
                    "ticket_id" => $ticket_id,
                    "status" => "done",
                    "sound" => $sound,
                    "android_channel_id" => "bell_sound_notification"
                ],
            "priority"  => "high",
            "data" =>
                [
                    'click_action' => 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
                    "ticket_id" => $ticket_id,
                    "title" => config('app.name'),
                    "body" => $body,
                    "status" => "done",
                ],
            "apns" =>
            [
                // "headers" =>
                // [
                //     'apns-priority' => '10',
                // ],
                "payload" =>
                [
                    "aps" =>[
                        'sound' => $sound,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];



        $dataString = json_encode($data);
        $client = new Client();
        $serviceAccountPath = storage_path('service-account-file.json');
   $client->setAuthConfig($serviceAccountPath);
   $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging');
   $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion();
   $accessToken = $token['access_token'];
         
        $headers = [
            'Authorization Bearer ' .$accessToken ,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            ];


        dispatch(function () use ($headers, $dataString) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/*projectname*/messages:send');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataString);
            $request = curl_exec($ch);
        });

    } 

I think I tried everything.
My service account role is owner, I tried also Firebase Cloud Messaging role.
Path to file is right. I also generated Oauth 2.0 token, and hardcoded it and it still not worked.
Firebase Cloud Messaging api is also enabled at Google Cloud.
